How to access scanner to scan document and save as a pdf using python
I am trying to build an application that can scan and print documents in windows using tkinter. I am able to print the documents using win32api and win32print
Now I want to scan the documents but could not find anything straight for starting point.
From where I can start digging about scanning documents ? Is there any module inside win32 library that could do this similar to win32print for printing ?

Thank you for your time and answer @KJ, I am looking into this so far I don't see any scanner in my paint application. I will update as soon as I figure this out.

Ok I tested and it is working, got a PNG file from python. Have to do bunch of adjustment but that is not a big deal. Thank you very much @KJ.

Take a look on pytwain.

@acw1668 pytwain is working with python32 and it is not able to see scanner with python64. I am looking into that though. If you have more details please share.

There isn't really an equivalent to pyinsane on Windows, you'll either commonly use the software that comes with the scanner or the API of the scanner. A lot of scanners do provide their own command-line tools or APIs for which you can do scanning tasks. To make things easier, Here's a method using the built-in Windows Fax and Scan utility, though this may need some handwork or scripting.
Using Windows Fax and Scan
Open the Windows Fax and Scan application -> Choose "New Scan" and configure -> your scanner settings -> Scan your document and save it as an image or PDF file
Automating with Scanner Software
Check if your scanner's manufacturer provides an API or command-line tool for automation (HP Smart, Canon My Image Garden).
You can use the tool's documentation to automate scanning via scripts.
